# Fill shape using ndimage.binary_fill_holes

Tags: python, numpy, io

I want to fill the central spot in this image, so that at the end that is white and the rest is black. I am trying to do it using `ndimage.binary_fill_holes` (code below). When I run my script, I get the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'`. What should I do to fix this?

```
 mask_filled = np.array(mask,numpy.uint16)
 ndimage.binary_fill_holes(mask_2, structure=np.ones((dim_x,dim_y)), origin=(75,75), output=mask_2_filled).astype(int)
 np.savetxt(filename_filled, mask_filled, fmt='%i')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`binary_fill_holes` doesn't return anything (well it returns `None`) if you provide the `output` array. Try this:

```
ndimage.binary_fill_holes(mask_2, structure=np.ones((dim_x,dim_y)), origin=(75,75),
                          output=mask_2_filled)
mask2filled = mask2filled.astype(int)
```

Or it seems like you could just not pass any ouput at all, that would save you needing to copy the array in the previous line. Also notice that in your question your variable names don't match, ie mask vs mask2, mask_filled vs mask_2_filled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, things are not yet fully working, but I hope to be on the right track ;-). I corrected a few misspelled variables name in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, it was easier than expected: following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914684/how-can-i-find-cycles-in-a-skeleton-image-with-python-libraries), the only line required is

```
mask_2_filled = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(mask_2)
```